# Large upload image file size

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have increment the file size. But still doesn't work, I would like to add any of these codes and increase the size of the file if it is accessible...

MySQL 5, PHP 5

```php
$permited  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$div = explode('.', $file_name);
$file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
$unique_image = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_ext;
$uploaded_image = "upload/" . $unique_image;


if ($title == "" || $cat == "" || $body == "" || $tags == "") {
    echo "<span class='error'> Must be Fill</span>";
} else {
    if (!empty($file_name)) {
        if ($file_size > 50048567) {


            echo "<span class='error'>Image Size should be less then 1MB!
    </span>";
        } elseif (in_array($file_ext, $permited) === false) {
            echo "<span class='error'>You can upload only:-"
                . implode(', ', $permited) . "</span>";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
            $query = "UPDATE  tbl_post
        SET
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java coding? If it is not directly relevent to an issue with coding in this language, please remove the [tag:java] tag from the question. No sense misleading folks who answer Java type questions as this can cause down-votes.

Comment: The code looks to be cut off and it is unclear what you mean by `increment the file size`. You just want to make a file larger than it actually is? (Unrelated but how is `50048567` related to 1 MB?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me but you can try this method below to check if there are errors while uploading.

```
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    // do you sql query
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: What did you change or how does this answer the question? Please put explanations in answers. Code dumps are not helpful usually.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.